# Separate lists in Redis

Tags: redis

Im bulding a game server where i'm holding a list of connected users and at the same time a list of battles, those 2 lists are seperate.

I'm holding the battles data in Redis db, with battle id as the key,
could I use the connected user list in the same Redis db and get a list of the connected users in a elegant way while avoining battles data ?

I couldn't find a solution for that and currently holding the connected users in JS dictionary in my nodeJs server

**UPDATE:**

to clarify queries,

connected user object is -

```
connectedUser = {
   nickname: string, (key)
   socketId: string,
   status: string,
   rating: number
}
```

i would like to query the data with getUser(nickname) which will fetch a specific user and getAllUsers() to fetch all connected users.

as for match it includes all match data and stats

```
match = {
   id: string, (key)
   nicknameOne: string,
   nicknameTwo: string,
   ...
}
```

on matches I query with id and believed it works well with hash table and hset and hget complexity wize.

as for queries on connected user, I wonder if using a simple js dictionary might provide with faster query results.

the js dictionary looks like that -

```
connectedUsers = {}
adding user - 
user  = {
  key: nickname,
  value: {
     socketId: string,
     status: string,
     rating: number
  }
}
```

while getting a specific user like that -

```
connectedUsers[nickname]
```

and iterating all this way -

```
for(let key in connectedUsers) {
   //value - connectedUsers[key];
}
```

Comment: Not sure it's clear which queries you want to support in the end. It would help if you can provide some examples of the data structure and queries you expect to have.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will beat the JS dictionary in terms of performance. Even with something as fast as Redis you're adding the overhead of interprocess communication (if hosted on the same machine) or network latencies.

If you want to use Redis for persistence, one way to store connected users would be to have a hash where keys are nicknames and values are user objects. You can do `HGET users-key userId` to get 1 user and `HGETALL users-key` to fetch all users.